# application of the metropolis criterion on neighbour in simulated annealing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I'm working on simulated annealing and i have some problem with the application of the Metropolis criterion. I use two methods:
First, i apply the metroplolis criterion on every neighbour generated and when i do this in my algorithm (i'm working with matlab), my algorithm refuses almost all neighbour and accepts only two or three, who are not even the best solutions,and at the end I have a result that is not the desired optimum. 
Second, when I generated a new neighboor,I compare his energy to the energy of the current solution , if it is less , I keep this neighbour , if this is not the case so I applied the criterion of Metroplis over to see if I keep it or not. In this way I get a satisfactory results. So I wonder if it's always the logic of simulated annealing, because i don't yet know when to apply this metropolis criterion. Is it on every generated neighbour? if it is the case, my second method is it correct? And also the random should be only between 0 and 1?or is it possible to generate a random in other interval? thank

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you are trying to solve and what you mean by " apply the metroplolis criterion on every neighbour " ?

Comment: I'm working on an optimization problem , precisely the optimization of cost 231 hata , which is a model propadation in mobile telecommunications networks. The metropolis criterion is: to calculate the exponential and generate a random number between zero and one, if

Comment: I have not understood the second part of your comment. I am curious about the * on every neighbour* part

Comment: sorry. Some problems with my network. I'm working on optimazation of cost 231 hata, which is a propagation model in mobile networks telecommunications. The Metroplis Criterion consist on: calculate an acceptance probability and generate a random number between 0 and 1; then compare this probability to  random number, if the probability is superior than the random number, then we accept the neighbour, if not it is rejected and we are supposed in  simulated annealing algorithm apply this criterion on every generated neighbour. @vib

Comment: So you should do the update by selecting a pair of adjacent vertices at random and applying Metropolis criterion to this pair. You still haven't explained what you mean by your "first" method but there are --a priori-- no guarantees that it will correctly sample your probability distribution.

Comment: i hope that you understand me now @vib

Comment: can i show you the general algorithm of simulated annealing?@v

Comment: I know simulated annealing. I know Metropolis criterion. I just don't understand what you are doing. What you should show is some of your code or (better) a detailed explanation of what you are trying to do and how you got about it in your two approaches

Comment: in the first method , when I generated a neighbour I calculate the probability of acceptance , if it is higher than random , I keep the neighbor , if not I reject it . The problem is that because of  the problem I'm trying to solve , my algorithm through this criterion rejects pratically all neighbour generated among which is my desired optimum. It accepts only 3 neighbors who do not sastify the problem posed. @vib

Comment: The ojective of my work is  to minimize the losses predicted by the propagation model cost 231 hata . I expressed if I can say it  the general form of the formula cost  231 hata as a vector.A form of my solution is a vector. I generated a vector, and I evaluated by my fitness function in view to minimize the losses. My fitness is the MSE(mean square error) and the optimum should have his MSE less than 8dB. @vib